# how to display an alert along with voice?

Tags: mobile-application, audio-player

I developed an app for kids and it includes some practice tests so when the answer is correct I wrote code to display alert `"correct"`. I want code for when displaying the alert `"correct"`. It should also come along with voice.

Comment: what is the platform your coding for?

Comment: Welcome to SO community, please read this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask it will help you to improve your chance of getting the correct answer

Comment: in what kind is this related to performance?

Comment: @AhmadKayyali, see Magic Links: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92060/185667

Comment: @brasofilo: I know Magic Links, it's just I am Lazy : )

Comment: @AhmadKayyali - So, gimme the link to Lazy Links :P

Comment: @brasofilo: here you go [Lazy Links](http://www.lazylinks.co.uk/)

Answer (score 2):

Get the path of the audio and then start the audio with the alertview and then you can stop it when the button is pressed.Something like this..

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/yourAudio.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1;
[audioPlayer play];
[alert show];
```

Stop the audio here.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
 if (buttonIndex==0) {

 [audioPlayer stop];

}
```

**Note : Add AVAudio framework and if youdon't want to play the audio untill the button of UIAlertView is clicked then set audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;**

Comment: how did you know it's not Android? is it **app for kids** that inspired you?

Comment: Answer is meant for ios only...